# How to ensure SetWindowsHookEx priority

Tags: winapi

I'm using SetWindowsHookEx to hook Keyboard ( idHook = WH_KEYBOARD ). In most case , the customer computers also running an Unicode Typing Software, it also hooking the keyboard with same method. So how i ensure my application run hook with highest priority or lowest priority than other software? (in some case i want my software with higher priority than the Unicode Typer, in some other case i want it run with lower priority)

Comment: That is not an option, whomever installs the hook later gets the notification first.  It is the CallNextHookEx() call in the callback function that chains it on to the next one.  You are not supposed to mess that up.  Hooks that do fumble this don't survive for very long :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook priorities are based on the order in which the hooks are installed.  Newer hooks have higher priority than older hooks.  There is no API exposed to query the order of existing hooks, so the only way to know if your hook is higher or lower than other hooks is to detour `SetWindowsHookEx()` itself in every running process and keep track of which processes are calling it.

The alternative is to stop using `SetWindowsHookEx()`, at least for high priority hooking.  Use the [RAW Input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) instead.  Then you will receive input events directly from the keyboard itself.  However, you cannot use RAW Input to block other processes from receiving keyboard input, if that is your goal.